# Blender to Sketchfab

Tags: animation, rigging

I have parented some armour to a shark model that is animated. I have then added some rotation animation to the armour to counter any clipping but when I export to sketchfab the secondary animation I did is just not on the model. When I try and rotate the armour in the same action as the shark the whole shark rotates. So is my only option to unparent the armour and then animate it to follow the shark? Surely you can have secondary animation on the armour and be able to export it as one full animation? When I bake actions it doesnt seem to also bake in the saddle (armour).

Comment: I assume you parented object to each other? Maybe try to add an empty object, and parent all top-level object to that empty, so that they are all in the same hierarchy. Then try to export again. If it doesn't work, try to use an armature instead of animating objects directly.

Comment: feel free to upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here if you want to allow us to check your project and give a more tailored answer.